# Insert Hyphen symbol between alphabet and numbers in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
 
# initialize data of lists.
data = {'Unique ID':['CCC-08559', 'CCC-0856A', 'CCC09512', '08565AAA','CCC-08565'],
        'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18, 15]}
 
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 
# Print the output.
df
```

With the help of regex, I want to insert hyphen symbol between alphabet and number in my dataframe and also print all the index where changes are made:
Example CCC09512 should be CCC-09512 in index 2.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: should `08565AAA` change to `08565-AAA`?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you could use a regex with lookarounds:

```
# replace LetterDigit to Letter-Digit or DigitLetter to Digit-Letter
s = df['Unique ID'].str.replace(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])',
                                '-', regex=True)
# identify changed column
df['changed'] = df['Unique ID'].ne(s)
# assign changed ID
df['Unique ID'] = s
```

output:

```
    Unique ID  Age  changed
0   CCC-08559   20    False
1  CCC-0856-A   21     True
2   CCC-09512   19     True
3   08565-AAA   18     True
4   CCC-08565   15    False
```

To limit to the first occurrence:

```
# replace LetterDigit to Letter-Digit or DigitLetter to Digit-Letter
s = df['Unique ID'].str.replace(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z])-?(?=\d)|(?<=\d)-?(?=[a-zA-Z])',
                                '-', n=1, regex=True)
# identify changed column
df['changed'] = df['Unique ID'].ne(s)
# assign changed ID
df['Unique ID'] = s
```

output:

```
   Unique ID  Age  changed
0  CCC-08559   20    False
1  CCC-0856A   21    False
2  CCC-09512   19     True
3  08565-AAA   18     True
4  CCC-08565   15    False
```

Comment: The second row is gonna be selected too. I ain't gonna downvote, but main question is why upvote?:)

Comment: @Amirhossein good point, I provided alternatives ;)